# Clean up authors in GitHub history after SVN migration

Tags: git, svn, github

I've moved my OSS project from SourceForge SVN to GitHub Git.
During the import I got a page where I could map the SF user names to the GitHub user names.

As my developers are only slowly creating their GitHub accounts I use to come back to that page and add the account as soon as I get to know it.

But when I look at the developers with `git shortlog -sne` now, I get for a few developers lines with their generic SF-transition name like

```
foo <foo@b3ce15a5-0815-abcd-b6eb-98bdc3a999cb>
...
Foo Bar <foobar@users.noreply.github.com>
```

where both are exactly the same account - one was the SF one and the other one is the GitHub one. And of course both were linked in the import tool as described above.

How can I unify these lines?

Can I use https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/ - without destroying the clones and forks that everybody has now?

(And what is meant by "After completing these steps, any person with forks or clones *must fetch the rewritten history and rebase any local changes into the rewritten history*"? I.e. what must be done exactly?)

Comment: Have you read the site you link to? It says right at the top that this is a destructive operation.

Comment: Sure I've read it - I've even put a quotation out of it in my question... "Destructive operation" is a very wide field. One that I can't judge. Will it require only a `git fetch` on every clone? Will it require more? What happens when the clones and forks are doing nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit seems to be what it means to perform a "destructive operation" and what it means to rewrite history that is already public, i.e., pushed.

In git parlance a destructive operation is one that performs operations on commits of a branch which result in an alternative history. The most often cited example is rebasing a branch that has already been pushed and probably pulled by others. `git filter-branch` which is used in your case is another example.

There are a lot of articles on the Web that explain why rebasing a public branch is a bad idea. The same applies to `filter-branch`. The gist of it is the following:

If you change anything in a commit C (including authoring information), C and any commit that has C as an ancestor will receive a new hash. In the simplest case, say, we have a branch and rewrite some commits. Now the branch cannot be pushed to the repository because a push can only add things on top. But rewriting created a parallel branch. It doesn't matter that it's almost the same as the old version, rewriting created a new hash and that's all that matters.

So changing the author in C in

```
A--B--C--D branch
```

results in

```
A--B--C--D branch
    \
     C'--D' branch'
```

In order to get it into the repo, you have to make a force push (`git push --force`). If someone else already created local commits on top of the branch, they have to be rebased onto the new version of the branch:

```
           E--F--G some-feature-branch
          /
A--B--C--D branch
    \
     C'--D' branch' (the new "truth")
```

must be rebased to

```
           E--F--G some-feature-branch
          /
A--B--C--D branch
    \
     C'--D' branch' (the new "truth")
          \
           E'--F'--G' some-feature-branch'
```

If you have only very few developers, you can solve this problem like this:

1. Tell everyone to push everything and stop working.
2. Perform your destructive operation.
3. Force push everything.
4. Tell everyone to pull. This will automatically update the branches and show a "forced update" indicator for every branch that is affected.

If you have many developers and simply cannot stop the commits, I don't think there is an solution that won't cause any mess. This is the (imho low) price you pay for integrity checks on the whole repository.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's an insightful answer! But I've got one more question, probably you can answer it as well: when I tell GitHub now (after the project was imported and being worked on by a few developers) a new mapping of SF-Developer <-> GitHub-Account it also does some internal stuff. Without telling me that it is dangerous/destructive... Is that doing something else - or is that exactly the same operation as in the posted link (https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)?

Comment: I'm not aware of a GitHub feature that allows you to provide such a mapping. If there is something like that ([this?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)), it could also be that GitHub maps the names used in the repository to GitHub user accounts. This mapping would not cause any changes in the repository.

Comment: Strange that I can't find anything about that feature about that. Not even a screenshot - so please have a look at mine ![GitHub Import](http://i.imgur.com/k2P3dBa.png?1).